# Upgrading from ngGrid to uiGrid (v2.0 to v3.0)

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have a web application, using ngGrid. Now I want to update to ui.grid. Thus I've been following this guide: [Upgrading ngGrid to uiGrid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/099_upgrading_from_2)

What I did is this:

- I've included the ui.grid js-file as well as the stylesheet
- Updated the directive to uiGrid rather than ngGrid="options"
- Use of grid.getCellValue(row, col) instead row.getProperty(col.field)
- Usage of grid.appScope in order to access variables from the controller scope

However, it won't work out for me. I'm always getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: gridFilterProvider <- gridFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/unpr?p0=gridFilterProvider%20%3C-%20gridFilter

    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at angular.js:3994
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4141)
    at angular.js:3999
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4141)
    at $get [as $filter] (angular.js:16516)
    at Parser.filter (angular.js:12118)
    at Parser.filterChain (angular.js:12112)
    at Parser.statements (angular.js:12091)
    at Parser.parse (angular.js:11948)
    at $parse (angular.js:12659)
```

I don't have a clue, where gridFilter is referenced or used. I even searched the whole project for 'gridFilter', but no result. Did someone face a similar issue or knows what this gridFiler actually is?

I'd really appreciate it, if someone could help me. Thanks already in advance!

Comment: any response?  Was the answer below correct?  If not, were you able to resolve your issue?  Please post the details!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need an answer for this, but here it is:

Your directive should actually be ui-grid="options" rather than uiGrid="options".

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps in your code - did you previously have gridFilter defined as a cellFilter on one of your columns?  I'm pretty sure I've never seen gridFilter in the ui-grid code base itself.